# Reading a text file of dictionaries stored in one line

Tags: python

## Question

I have a text file that records metadata of research papers requested with [SemanticScholar API](https://api.semanticscholar.org/). However, when I wrote requested data, I forgot to add `"\n"` for each individual record. This results in something looks like

```
{<metadata1>}{<metadata2>}{<metadata3>}...
```

and this should be if I did add `"\n"`.

```
{<metadata1>}
{<metadata2>}
{<metadata3>}
...
```

Now, I would like to read the data. As all the metadata is now stored in one line, I need to do some hacks

- First I split the cluttered dicts using `"{"`.
- Then I tried to convert the string `line` back to dict. Note that I do consider `line` might not be in a proper JSON format.

```py
import json
with open("metadata.json", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readline().split("{"):
        print(json.loads("{" + line.replace("\'", "\"")))
```

However, there is still an error message

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I am wondering what should I do to recover all the metadata I collected?

### MWE

Note, in order to get `metadata.json` file I use, use the following code, it should work out of the box.

```py
import json
import urllib
import requests

baseURL = "https://api.semanticscholar.org/v1/paper/"
paperIDList = ["200794f9b353c1fe3b45c6b57e8ad954944b1e69",
               "b407a81019650fe8b0acf7e4f8f18451f9c803d5",
               "ff118a6a74d1e522f147a9aaf0df5877fd66e377"]

for paperID in paperIDList:
    response = requests.get(urllib.parse.urljoin(baseURL, paperID))
    metadata = response.json()
    record = dict()
    record["title"] = metadata["title"]
    record["abstract"] = metadata["abstract"]
    record["paperId"] = metadata["paperId"]
    record["year"] = metadata["year"]
    record["citations"] = [item["paperId"] for item in metadata["citations"] if item["paperId"]]
    record["references"] = [item["paperId"] for item in metadata["references"] if item["paperId"]]
    with open("metadata.json", "a") as fileObject:
        fileObject.write(json.dumps(record))
```

Comment: we cant help you without seeing the metadata...

Comment: i suggest you to use pickle.dump()  and pickle.load() instead of JSON for manipulating the file

Comment: Why not re-create the metadata.json file with the `\n` at the end of each record?

Comment: @adirabargil I have already provided the script to get `metadata.json` in MWE section.

Comment: @LeonardoScotti Yes. This is a good solution for smaller files. But in my case, there are almost half a million records and directly using `pickle.dump()` is problematic.

Comment: @VighneshRaut Thank you for pointing this out! As is pointed out in the accepted answer, I think this is a much better solution than what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do the `split("{")` you get a first item that is empty, corresponding to the opening `{`. Just ignore the first element and everything works fine (I added an `r` in your quote replacements so python considers then as [strings literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals) and replace them properly):

```
with open("metadata.json", "r") as f:
     for line in f.readline().split("{")[1:]:
         print(json.loads("{" + line).replace(r"\'", r"\""))
```

As suggested in the comments, I would actually recommend recreating the file or saving a new version where you replace `}{` by `}\n{`:

```
with open("metadata.json", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
data_lines = data.replace("}{","}\n{")
with open("metadata_mod.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(data_lines)
```

That way you will have the metadata of a paper per line as you want.

Comment: Thank you! I think recreating the entire file is a great solution.

Comment: You are welcome. I just edited the answer with a correction. You don't need to remove the replace, just use the proper syntax.